# Configuring egit with BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I decided to try BitBucket and Git but I'm confused on how to configuring eGIT ( Eclipse GIT plugin ) to connect to Bitbucket's GIT repo.

Anybody know any documentation on this? Thanks.

Update : I gave up to solve the issue, and currently using SourceTree, which is a simple tool to deal with this. It's a free tool created by Attlasian ( the company that created Jira ).

Comment: Coming from Subclipse I'm having drama working out how to use eGit too. It doesn't seem straight forward or I need more coffee

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I have found this url very useful

http://wangpidong.blogspot.com.es/2012/05/how-to-use-bitbucket-with-egit-in.html

Comment: I found these steps especially useful: 1) Window > Preferences > General > Network Connections > SSH2; 2) Key Management tab; 3) Click the button Generate RSA Key; click the button Save Private Key.

Answer (score 8):

Your question is essentially asking for documentation on using egit - you can find that all here:

- http://eclipse.org/egit/documentation/

In particular, the user manual that is linked from there describes both how to clone a repository using EGit and work with an existing repository — it's not clear from your question which situation you are in.  The only difference between using a BitBucket git repository and one from another repository-hosting service is the URL, essentially.  Broadly speaking, you should use the SSH URL if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You may run into egit authentication problems while pushing. 
To solve that problem you can open up the git repository viewer and add a remote repository.
More details can be found here: http://lechmigdal.blogspot.com/2012/08/eclipse-egit-authenticity-of-host-cant.html