# github in Eclipse - not able to push a branch upstream from local

Tags: eclipse, git, github, ssh

I have a project setup at github remote. I cloned the project in Eclipse, created a branch in local folder and when I try push the branch to the upstream, it says `push not permitted`

I am getting this message in Configure push window:

> Note that remote 'origin' is used from 1 other branches (see tooltip for a list)

Note : I have setup the Eclipse with ssh keys and included it in remote git-hub account as well. I was able to clone the project in local using ssh but not push it.

Please help me to push a branch created in local to remote github repository.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't push using EGit and Bitbucket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481935/cant-push-using-egit-and-bitbucket)

Comment: please put in a little more search effort in the future. Or, if you did so and no other solutions have solved your problem, please mention that (if possible providing links to/descriptions of everything you have tried). :)

Comment: @Julio btw, a) that command is wrong (it's `git push <remote> <branch>`), and b) checking out master has nothing to do with push permission problems

Comment: @NevikRehnel sorry, removed.

Comment: @NevikRehnel Thanks for your comments. I have made required search efforts as well as I tried all possible ways to use both HTTPS and SSH. In SSH, i am getting the above error and with HTTPS I am getting this error "git-receive-pack not permitted". Also the link you gave as possible duplicate does not help me a lot. I verified that link even before you posted. Thanks for taking time to review my problem. Please let me know if you can help me. As per my investigation, I may require to get some kind of access from git admin in our company which I am going to try tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue using SSH.

A straight forward answer.

"Please have the code Repository owner give access to the git code base." After I got the access from owner I was able to push it to remote.