# Integrate Jira, Bitbucket to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jira, bitbucket

I'm trying to integrate everything on Eclipse, I managed to link eclipse and Jira, but I don't know how to use the code from bitbucket.

I'd like to use the code from bitbucket through Jira to have it in just one place, cause if I use separately bitbucket I won't have the integration I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

Jira and bitbucket integrate with each other. You may need to register separately though. http://blog.bitbucket.org/2012/04/30/linking-bitbucket-and-jira/

You can use EGit to have bitbucket using git to be working with eclipse - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13332618/2279816

This would mean you commit to bitbucket through eclipse, mention the jira Id in the commit message and there will be corresponding links appearing in jira.

Comment: I've used plain-jane EGit to link up a BitBucket repo to my eclipse project.