# Arrow up and number on Eclipse meaning

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven

I'm working on a project using Eclipse with Maven and Bitbucket. Right now I can't do any commit, I mean even if I press the commit button, I can't see it on Bitbucket. Furthermore, next to my project's name I got a symbol with an arrow up and the number 2 next to it.

What does it means? What should I do?

Comment: The 2 arrows mean that you have commited twice into your local repository, but you haven't pushed it to the server. Right click on the project->Team->Push. For this to work you need to have set up the remotes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906529/configuring-egit-with-bitbucket

Answer (score 21):

This means your local branch is two commits ahead of the remote one. Git is a distributed version control system. The `git commit` command only introduces the changes to your local repository. To make them appear in the remote, you have to use `git push` after committing your changes.

Alternatively, you can use Eclipse as a GUI to perform the same steps. In the context menu that pops up when you right-click the project, there should be a `Team` option. Clicking it brings up another context menu, which should have a `Push` option.